# Crear dos atributos en la misma Trn, con los mismos datos, pero de diferente tipo

Tags: datetime, genexus, transacciones

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente. En mi base de datos tengo una tabla pedido con el campo "PedidoFecha" del tipo DateTime, y lo estoy usando para cargar un objeto TimeLine Chart. Por defecto, gracias al tipo de dato, el chart carga los datos y los agrupa en Segundos, y necesito que me los agrupe en días. Ya que no tengo posibilidad de cambiar el tipo de dato de la BD, necesito una forma de transformarlo al tipo Date, y que pueda usarlo como atributo.

Hasta ahora probé con transacciones dinámicas, pero se me dificulto bastante entenderlo y tuve un par de problemas asi que descarté la opción. Luego probé añadiendo atributos formula, pero no pude lograr que tomaran ningun valor. También probé utilizando un dataprovider, asignando al atributo "PedidoFecha.ToDate()" y tampoco tuve resultado.

No se si como lo hice yo es o era la forma correcta de hacerlo, pero no se me ocurre que más intentar. Espero su respuesta! Desde ya gracias. Si necesitan mas info me la piden.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es crear el Atributo fórmula `PedidoNuevaFecha` de tipo `Date`

```
PedidoNuevaFecha = YMDtoD(PedidoFecha.Year(),PedidoFecha.Month(),PedidoFecha.Day())
```